# Modrewrite на nginx+apache

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

На сервере стоит nginx+apache.

```
location ~* ^(?!/папка/).+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|js)${
            set $rflag 1;
            if (-e $request_filename) { 
                set $rflag 0;
            }
            if ($rflag = 1) {
                proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:81;
                break;
            }
}

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:81;
    }
```

в nginx'e стоит такой параметр, и отлично все работает. т.е. указанные файлы кроме папки - отдает nginx

и есть папка с картинками. которая через apache обрабатывалась бы вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/upload/map/)
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^upload/map/([A-z]+)/(.*).jpg$ /ban/img.php?opt1=$1&opt2=$2
```

и код img.php

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(250, 187); 
if(!$i = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/map/origins/{$opt1}/{$opt2}.jpg")){
    $i = imagecreatefromjpeg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/default.jpg");
    imagecopyresampled($img, $i, 0, -30, 0, 0, 250, 250, 300, 300);
    imagejpeg($img); 
}else{
    imagecopyresampled($img, $i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 250, 187, 250, 187);   
    $i2 = @imagecreatefrompng($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/watermark.png");
    imagecopyresampled($img, $i2, 210, 135, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    imagejpeg($img, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/map/{$opt1}/{$opt2}.jpg"); 
    imagejpeg($img); 
}
```

Как сделать что бы nginx обрабатывал эти картинки так же как и apache?
Иначе

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^(/upload/map/)"){ rewrite ^/upload/map/([A-z]+)/(.*).jpg$ /ban/imgmap.php?opt1=$1&opt2=$2; }
```

ни к чему не приводит

Comment: Мда. Руки отрывать за такой конфиг. Попробуйте сформулировать русским языком что должно происходить в разных случаях в разных папках. Я на 99% уверен, что все эти задачи можно решить без if с помощью try_files.

Comment: @alexey-ten, что бы nginx обрабатывал только существующие картинки в папке, а несуществующие отдавал скрипту php(который в свою очередь выполняется на apache)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Долго писать, [проще прочитать](https://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+Nginx_20160622)

Используйте  директиву try_files:

server {
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/site;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }
    location @proxy {
...
    }
}